# react-native : Can I use props in a method?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have my class and  I have a method and I am wondering if I could use `props` inside a mehtod.

Notice I try to use props in `methodTwo`. Is this possible? If not, is there a way I could use `props in method`?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class Test extends React.PureComponent {

  methodOne = () => {
    this.setState({
      one:false,
      two:false,
      three:false
    })
  }

  methodTwo = () => {
    this.setState({
      one:false,
      two:false,
//I want to use props
      three:this.props.three
    })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={{   backgroundColor: 'transparent', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Button title='one' onPress={()=>this.methodOne()}/>

// I could call i like this?
        <Test three='newState'/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can use props like that.

Comment: @kirimi what problem are you facing because you can use props

Comment: Do you know how to I access the props when I call the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  methodTwo = () => {
    this.setState({
      one:false,
      two:false,
      three:this.props.three
    })
  }
```

props-> is the value that is been transferred from parent component to child component.
In class based component you fetch the value by using **this.props.Attribute_name** and in functional based component you can fetch the value using **props.Attribute_name** (mind functional based component dont have any concept of this)

if you want to use this.props.three ,then in parent component call  (the component calling this particular component) `<Test three="anyValue" />` then you can easily get this value in child component.

```js
class Cat extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const mouse = this.props.mouse;
    return (
      <img src="/cat.jpg" style={{ position: 'absolute', left: mouse.x, top: mouse.y }} />
    );
  }
}

class MouseWithCat extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleMouseMove = this.handleMouseMove.bind(this);
    this.state = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  }

  handleMouseMove(event) {
    this.setState({
      x: event.clientX,
      y: event.clientY
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ height: '100%' }} onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove}>

        {/*
          We could just swap out the <p> for a <Cat> here ... but then
          we would need to create a separate <MouseWithSomethingElse>
          component every time we need to use it, so <MouseWithCat>
          isn't really reusable yet.
        */}
        <Cat mouse={this.state} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class MouseTracker extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Move the mouse around!</h1>
        <MouseWithCat />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I edited my code. Do I access it like this?

Comment: No, which Component is calling this Test component? there might be any component where you are calling as its been exported. there you have to call

Comment: I am trying to call it from Test component.

Comment: @kirimi i have added the code snippet check the example and let me know if any further doubts you have.Go through the code

Answer (score 0):

The props are accessible to whole of the class scope with the syntax `this.props.xxxx` if you have passed it from its parent component. SO you can use in methodOne too.

Comment: yes, but I want to know how I can access the props.

Comment: you are accessing the props by `this.props.xxxx` itself.  You pass it like < Test name ="gaurav" /> and then you access in Test class anywhere by `this.props.name`. Any doubts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use props inside a method. Any specific error you are facing ?.

Comment: Yes, How can I call in the render method?